# Trying to get the memberid from table

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get the memberid from database according to text entered in the textbox like this way

```
String sql =@" SELECT member_Id FROM members where (member_Firstname,'',member_Lastname) ="+tbMemberName.Text;
```

How can this be done?

Comment: what is the final query printed? What error you got ? What is this where (member_Firstname,'',member_Lastname)

Comment: I want to get the memberid from database where membername enter in the textbox  but in member table i have two columns for member name first one is member firstname and another one is member lastname. would you pls suggest that the above syntax is appropriate one.I am using MYSQL as database

Comment: what value is entered into the 'textbox'?  first and last name?

Comment: first and lastname like  ----   Alex raj    ---- alex is the firstname and raj is the secondname

Comment: What platform is being used to call into MySQL? PHP, C#, Python?

Comment: @user1, are you sure that's PHP with C#?  I don't even think that's a real thing....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
String sql =@" SELECT member_Id FROM members where CONCAT(member_Firstname,'',member_Lastname) = '"+tbMemberName.Text+"'";
```

Also, this is vulnerable to sql injection.

Comment: would give any idea about this

Answer (score 0):

Due to security and performance reasons, I would personally split the members's name in first/ last *before* compiling the query. Now, I'm not familiar with the language you use to call this query, but I'll formulate something that will hopefully make sense, regardless of it's stupidity:

```
String sql =@" SELECT member_Id FROM members WHERE member_Lastname = "+safely_escaped(tbMembername.Last.Text)+" AND member_Firstname = "+safely_escaped(tbMembername.First.Text)+"
```

This will allow for a more precise analysis of the names before inserting it into the query and it will allow you to use an index (which is not possible with any of the previously shown examples). Just to be clear, the index, most efficiently in this case, would be INDEX (member_Lastname, member_Firstname).

Answer (score 0):

If that's C# that you're writing, as you've commented, you'll want to start using parameters to avoid SQL injection.

```
string getMember= @"SELECT member_Id FROM members 
                    WHERE member_Firstname like @userText
                    OR    member_Lastname like  @userText;";

MySqlCommand m = new MySqlCommand(getMember);
m.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userText", tbMemberName.Text + "%");

var reader = m.ExecuteReader();
```